# creating firebase rules function that checks for limited image names that can be added to storage?

Tags: firebase-storage, firebase-security

I have the following function that works fine until I add the following check

> request.resource.name.matches('^[1-9][0-9]{0,19}$')

My goal is to use a wildcard image, as the image in my case could have names ranging from 1 to 20. However, I am having issues making the name regex work. Additionally, the images can only be in PNG or WebP format; no other types are allowed. Therefore, I can have for example 5 PNGs and 15 WebPs. the limit is set to 20 images. What is the correct way to check for the name in this case?

```js
 // Clinet side storage ref 
 //`construction-equipment/${uid}/custom-equipment/${storageName}` // 1-20
 
 // Rules 
 rules_version = '2';
  service firebase.storage {
  match /b/project-your-construction-tools-2aa88-users/o {  
  
  // Private functions
  // Checks for custom equipment number of images type and size and 
  function customEquipmentImageCheck(image) { 
  return ( 
    request.resource.name.matches('^[1-9][0-9]{0,19}$') && // Only 20 images 
    (request.resource.contentType.matches('image/webp') || // webp (for web) 
    request.resource.contentType.matches('image/png')) &&  // png (for iOS)
    request.resource.size < 256000 // only 256KB for custom equipment images
  );
  }
  
  
  // Match (User Custom Equipment images file)
  match /construction-equipment/{userId}/custom-equipment/{image} {
  
  // Allow Get
  allow get: if true

  // Allow Create 
  allow write: customEquipmentImageCheck(image)
  
  // Allow Update
  allow update: if customEquipmentImageCheck(image)
  
  // Allow Delete
  allow delete: if false

  }
```